# how to fill color to image in canvas using fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

I have added three images to which I need to fill colour based on certain values. I have used fabric js to fill the canvas with an image from URL

I had tried using hue rotation to fill the image but one image was red, another yellow and another one green. need to fill all 3 images with the same colour

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');       
fabric.Image.fromURL('leftspeedometer.png', function(img){
  img.set('left', 70);
  img.set('top', 100);
  canvas.add(img);
});
```